What are some effective warmups/excercices for open throat singing before actual singing or performance?
Soo, I am studying open throat singing to learn natural vibrato & control tension on my riff and runs/melisma...
I don't know but when I try to do some open throat singing of which I followed on Youtube, I feel like many air is pushing through my throat like a sense of low to high relaxation but only there... like my entire neck feels relaxed
May I ask, is this correct?
Also, Can anyone recommend me effective open throat warmups/excercises before actual singing a song/performance?
